# Modify the content of specific line in text file

Tags: c#, file, text, line

I'm new on c# and currently working on project so that I need to open an existing text file and editing the content of a specific line (i.e. 32) but I failed! Any help?

Answer (score 28):

Well, based on your question you know the line number, so do something like this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("path to file");
lines[31] = "some value";
File.WriteAllLines("path to file", lines);
```

the first line of code gets you all the lines of a file into an array. The second line clearly sets thy known line to some value, and the third line overwrites the file with the new set of lines.

Comment: I was writing this as you submitted it! Seems like the most logical answer.

Comment: @Nathan, thanks! I'm pretty sure for the OP's case it is anyway. Great minds think alike huh?

Comment: I'd certainly like to think so!

Comment: this would be a good solution for smaller files, what if you had a big file though? this would load it all into memory